# What's the sharpest frequency response for a non-causal low-pass filter whose step response doesn't overshoot?

Tags: filter, dsp

Butterworth, Bessel, Chebychev, and sinc low-pass filters are used in various cases where there are different tradeoffs between having a uniformly-decreasing frequency response, a uniform phase response, a steep cutoff, or "brick-wall" response.  I believe all such filters can, in some cases, can have overshoot on their step response, meaning their impulse response is in some places negative.

What would be the optimal frequency response, or what types of frequency responses would be available, in a filter whose only constraint was that the impulse response could not be negative anyplace?  Certainly it's possible to have a low-pass filter meeting such a constraint, since a basic RC filter will do so (though the response of such a filter is a bit crummy).  Would the optimal impulse response be a normal distribution curve, or something else?

Comment: @supercat, if you include digital filtering, it is pretty amazing how brick wall a response you can get without overshoot.

Comment: @Kortuk: Really?  I would think it would be hard to avoid overshoot, since a brick-wall-filtered square wave has little spikes whose width approaches zero as the cutoff frequency rises but whose amplitude does not.  What would be a good reference?

Comment: @supercat, I am sorry to say I do not have good references to teach about digital filtering, I have taken classes and designed filters. The advantage to a digital filter is the order you can implement easily and ideally.

Comment: You say "non-causal" in the question, but all your examples are causal.  Which do you mean?  Non-causal requires you to record the entire waveform and then apply the filter to the recording. (Or, perhaps, the use of flux capacitors and large power sources.)

Comment: @endolith: What would be the optimum filter, assuming it's not required to be causal.

Comment: @endolith: In some contexts, overshoot is simply not possible.  For example, some types of signals have absolute limits one way or another.  Also, there are some physical ways of implementing filtering which only work with positive impulse functions (e.g. the spot function on a film recorder can only lay down light; it can't erase it).

Comment: @supercat, it is a digital filter, why not just have a simple check, if (signal<0) signal=0;?

Comment: @Kortuk: Clipping the signal at zero is going to totally annihilate any benefits of filtering.  And while I'm posting in DSP, I'm also curious about things like audio film recorders (from an intellectual rather than practical aspect admittedly) where one can make whatever non-negative impulse function one wants, subject to a width constraint.

Comment: @supercat, if you have a signal that is bouncing negative that should not be negative, it is not going to be harmed by that clipping. An ideal low pass will not bounce negative at all as long as you give a small loss the the lowest AC frequency and have a  large bias like a square wave would. If you are talking about analog system you are going to have to bias your signal to not go negative.

Comment: @Kortuk: Suppose one is trying to design a video projector to show continuous-tone pictures.  Although one could design it to show hard-edged pixels, those will add high-frequency visual components which are useful when displaying text, but which may cause aliasing when showing graphics whose frequency components approach Nyquist.  If one properly blurred the pixels so they overlapped properly, one could minimize the aliasing effects.  It's impossible, though, to spread the light from one pixel so it darkens other pixels, though.

Comment: @Kortuk: The pattern of light produced by a single pixel would correspond to the impulse function of a low-pass filter.  If the pattern is too broad, it will attenuate frequencies well below Nyquist; if it's too narrow, it won't do a good job of attenuating frequencies above Nyquist.  It would seem like there should be some way of characterizing the optimal frequency response that could be obtained under such constraints.

Comment: @supercat, I wish I could sit down with a whiteboard and see how I miss-communicating with you. There is something you are saying that I am not interpreting correctly. I hope as answer show up I learn what I am not interpreting.

Comment: @Kortuk: Filters have many applications, some dealing with time frequency and others with spacial frequency in one, two, or more dimensions.  In some applications, one may be constrained to either have a uniformly-positive impulse function, or not have an output which overshoots the behavior of the input.  I don't think it's mathematically possible for a brick-wall filter to achieve such behavior (some attenuation of signals below the cutoff is necessary to avoid ringing) but I don't know what the actual limit is.

Comment: @supercat, you have peaked my interest, I will get my matlab working again and see what I can do. I do not agree that you must have attenuation in the lower frequencies to stop overshoot. An ideal low pass filter would generate a perfect sinusoid from a square wave(if the cutoff is designed for that).

Comment: @Kortuk: An brick-wall low-pass filter which was between the first and third overtones of a square wave would pass through a nice simple sine wave, but what about one between the third and fifth?

Comment: @supercat, I think I understand what is being asked about. I think it is the non-ideal components that are used in analog filtering that cause affects like this, with an ideal low pass you would not have the overshoot. It is officially on my to do list to spend some time on this and try to make you a real answer. Give me a month.

Comment: @Kortuk: Any further thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps this question would fit better over at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This question should be migrated to DSP.SE, where it will get better answers.  It's about digital filtering, not electronics.

Comment: Is it ok for the step response to ring a lot, as long as the ringing doesn't overshoot (stays between the low and high amplitude values of the step)?  See Figure 6 in http://www.smp.uq.edu.au/people/YoniNazarathy/Control4406/resources/HoaggBernsteinNonMinimumPhaseZero.pdf for an example.  Or do you want the step response to be monotonic?

Comment: @Kortuk: I'm commenting on this now because this question was offered by the system as being relevant to a recent question. You said, *"An ideal low pass filter would generate a perfect sinusoid from a square wave."* Keep in mind that the peak of that sinusoid will exceed the level of the original squarewave by a factor of 4/pi. That counts as "overshoot" in my book.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Interesting point, which would perhaps suggest that an ideal non-overshoot filter shouldn't be a brick wall, but should attenuate slightly at frequencies approaching the cutoff.

Comment: Yes. A very long time ago, I remember reading that the "ideal" response for an oscilloscope was a Gaussian filter, since this gave the best tradeoff between bandwidth and waveform distortion.

Comment: @DaveTweed: One of the reasons I asked this question, and one I remain interested in it, is that the design of anti-aliasing filters for cameras essentially entails designing the impulse function, and it can't go negative.  It's important that the image which hits the actual sensing element not have any components above Nyquist, but at the same time one doesn't want to excessively blur content below Nyquist.  Since I wrote the question, I've observed that to an increasing extent broadcast video content seems to be shot with a near-brick-wall filter, which is a mixed blessing.

Comment: @DaveTweed: A brick wall filter is excellent when there is a lot of interesting content slightly below Nyquist, and no comparable content slightly above.  A filter with a more gradual roll-off would be better in cases where content straddles Nyquist.  Consequently, there may be some value in having a camera with a resolution significantly above that of the intended output device, since capturing at a higher resolution would allow one to avoid having to commit to any sort of anti-aliasing filter characteristics in the frequencies of interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to list of bunch of "filters that don't overshoot".
I hope you'll find this partial answer better than no answer at all.
Hopefully people looking for "a filter that doesn't overshoot" will find this list of such filters helpful.
Perhaps one of these filters will work adequately in your application, even if we haven't found the mathematically optimum filter yet.

**first and second order LTI causal filters**

The step response of a first order filter ("RC filter") never overshoots.

The step response of a second order filter ("biquad") can be designed such that it never overshoots.
There are several equivalent ways of describing this class of second-order filter that doesn't overshoot on a step input:

- it is critically damped or it is overdamped.
- it is not underdamped.
- the damping ratio (zeta) is 1 or more
- the quality factor (Q) is 1/2 or less
- the decay rate parameter (alpha) is at least the undamped natural angular frequency (omega_0) or more

In particular, a unity gain Sallen–Key filter topology with equal capacitors and equal resistors is critically damped: Q = 1/2 , and therefore does not overshoot on a step input.

A second-order Bessel filter is slightly underdamped: Q = 1/sqrt(3) , so it has a little overshoot.

A second-order Butterworth filter is more underdamped: Q = 1/sqrt(2) , so it has more overshoot.

Out of all possible first-order and second-order LTI filters that are causal and do not overshoot, the one with the "best" (steepest) frequency response are the "critically damped" second-order filters.

**higher-order LTI causal filters**

The most commonly-used higher-order causal filter that has an impulse response that is never negative (and therefore never overshoots on a step input) is the "running average filter", also called the "boxcar filter" or the "[moving average filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/moving_average)".

Some people like to run data through one boxcar filter, and the output from that filter into another boxcar filter.
After a few such filters, the result is a good approximation of the Gaussian filter.
(The more filters you cascade, the closer the final output approximates a Gaussian, no matter what filter you start with -- boxcar, triangle, first-order RC, or any other -- because of the central limit theorem).

Practically all [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/window_function) have an impulse response that is never negative, and so in principle can be used as FIR filters that never overshoot on a step input.
In particular, I hear good things about the [Lanczos window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_window),
which is the central (positive) lobe of the sinc() function (and zero outside that lobe).
A few [pulse shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/pulse_shaping) filters have an impulse response that is never negative, and so can be used as filters that never overshoot on a step input.

I don't know which of these filters is the best for your application, and I suspect the mathematically optimum filter may be slightly better than any of them.

**non-linear causal filters**

The [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/median_filter) is a popular non-linear filter that never overshoots on a step-function input.

EDIT: **LTI noncausal filters**

The function sech(t) = 2/( e^(-t) + e^t ) is its own Fourier transform, and I suppose could be used as a kind of non-causal low-pass LTI filter that never overshoots on a step input.

The non-causal LTI filter that has the (sinc(t/k))^2 impulse response has a "abs(k)*triangle(k*w)" frequency response.
When given a step input, it has a lot of time-domain ripple, but it never overshoots the final settling point.
Above the high-frequency corner of that triangle, it gives perfect stop-band rejection (infinite attenuation).
So in the stop band region, it has better frequency response than a Gaussian filter.

Therefore I doubt the Gaussian filter gives the "optimal frequency response".

In the set of all possible "filters that don't overshoot", I suspect there is no one single "optimal frequency response" -- some have better stop-band rejection, while others have narrower transition bands, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'd neglected to restrict my question to linear filters, though of course characterizing the frequency response of a non-linear filter can be a murky proposition.  As noted, cascading the boxcar filter causes it to approach a Gaussian.  I was wondering if the Gaussian filter has the optimal frequency response that can be obtained without overshoot.  In writing the question, I was thinking about various analogue processes which perform something like a defined impulse-response filter, e.g. blurring camera or display pixels to minimize aliasing.

Comment: It's possible to construct a camera so that each pixel picks up varying amounts of light from various points around the center.  Ideally, a camera would filter out everything above Nyquist without blurring anything below, but in practice that's not likely to happen.

Comment: LTI? You never define it. Adding that it means "linear time-invariant", would probably be helpful.

Comment: So Q = 0.5 is critically-damped?  For a given order, are there multiple systems that are critically-damped?  The biquad with Q = 0.5 is called the LR2 [Linkwitz-Riley filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkwitz%E2%80%93Riley_filter).  Looks like higher-order versions of the LR filter have ringing in the step response, though.

Comment: ["cascading critically-damped filters will result in another critically-damped filter"](http://unicorn.us.com/alex/2polefilters.html)  So just keep dumping poles at -1 and it will always be critically-damped?  (And approach a Gaussian filter response as the number increases?)

Comment: A Gaussian filter is an excellent one to have in your toolbox. Doesn't overshoot, tuned with a single parameter, has smallest product (is the most compact) of spread in both time and frequency domains, and is pretty good whether you need a filter or an FFT window, but usually never the best according to some optimality criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the filters used in the digital world are just sampled version of the analog counterpart. A large reason for this is that there was lots of work done in analog filtering before digital came along, so rather then reinventing the wheel, most just used prior designs. The advantage to digital though is that a higher order filter can be achieved much easier then in the analog world. Just imagine of complex a circuit get every time you add another order to the design.

If you are going for a brick wall type filter the Gaussian curve is a pretty good place to start. If you know about Time Domain <-> Frequency Domain; a Gaussian transforms into a Gaussian in the other domain. As it gets winder in one, it gets narrower in the other. So in order to get a perfect spike in frequency domain you would need an infinite amount of samples.

If you happen to have Matlab available for use, you should check out some of the built in filter design tools. Here is a link talking about [Butterworth](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/butter.html) and [Bessel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/besself.html). The design tools allows you to specify certain aspects of the filter. These aspects changes for each filter type, but some examples are Passband, stopband, ripple, etc. If you give the designer the constraints you want, it will either give you an error (meaning it can't make that filter with that filter type) or it will give you a filter with the minimum order required to meet spec.

Comment: A [Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) fits the requirement for a nonnegative impulse response, but it's not much of a brick wall. On the other hand, Butterworth, Bessel, and Chebyshev have sinc-like oscillations in their impulse response, leading to overshoot. Of those the [Bessel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter) has the least overshoot since it has a nearly flat group delay (linear phase) in the passband.

Comment: Other than the Gaussian, these filters are causal. For offline processing, a linear phase NNFIR (nonnegative FIR) would work well, or you can cancel the phase distortion of a causal recursive filter by using the *filtfilt* technique.... Of course you still need a way to design an NNIR LPF to avoid overshoot/undershoot. Suggestions anyone? References?

Comment: @eryksun, as a side note, if it is going to oscillate at 1.05 times the value max, just damp that to stop at 1.00 and your step response will be a little less, like .96 when stable. Problem solved.

Comment: @Kortuk: Problem solved in the time domain, but doing that clipping is not only non-linear but also opens certain parts of the frequency domain to pass signal that didn't previously.  He wants to the tightest possible pass / no pass filter in frequency without overshoot in the time domain.  No time domain overshoot is the same as saying the impulse response is never negative.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, not clipping, scaling. For overshoot if you know the design will overshoot will go over by 3% scale the entire signal, that is not clipping and is a linear time invariant solution.

Comment: @Kortuk: In some domains, zero is near the midpoint between maximum and minimum, and scaling a signal toward the midpoint will avoid problems with overshoot.  In other domains, such as imaging, zero *is* the minimum, and dynamic range is most important there; it would generally be better to have a "fuzzier" filter that doesn't overshoot than a sharper one that does.